# What to use instead of <c:forEach in .blur function

Tags: jsp, hashmap, jstl, matching

I have read many many questions and answers when trying to loop through a HaspMap in JSP
Most point to using the jstl taglib making use of the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${myHashMap}" var="units">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

however this will not work in the following place (see - ...???...) :  What I am trying to do is when a input text field looses focus I want to match whatever is inside that field against a Hashmap that I have previously provided from my controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#someInput").blur(function(){
            ... ??? ... 
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I have 2 questions:

**1:** *What can I use to loop through a HashMap inside a JSP function?*

**2:** *What can I read to see which functions are available to me inside the jsp  area keeping in mind that I want to avoid scriptlets.*

Many Thanks

Sean

**BAH ...:** ***-Possible Solution-***

So I found a solution to this already (I think)...

```
var csm = ${cs};
var keysArray = new Array();
for (var key in csm) {
    keysArray.push(key);
}
```

Then I simply loop through the Array in a while loop as follows:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < keysArray.length) {
    if ( (var1_toCheck === keysArray[i]) && (var2_toCheck === csm[keysArray[i]])) {
        alert("**WARNING**\n\nYou have found a match!");
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The match is still not working but I am still working on that ...

Any suggestions to improve my solution will be appreciated.

Cheers
Sean

**And ... I fixed the matching also**

The controller is sending a Hashmap consisting of   but I was not parsing the value I receive from the inputfield.

so I changed this

```
var val1_toCheck = $("#val1").val();
```

to this

```
var val1_toCheck = parseInt($("#val1").val());
```

Seems to be working great now.

As I mentioned previously ... if there are better ways to accomplish what I was trying to do I would appreciate the pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java `HashMap` object is only defined and understood by a JVM on the server.  You need to put the data composing it into a structure that can be used by Javascript in your user's browser.  Your possible solution will work, but then you'd have to do work on the server side to put each key into a `List` object and serialize that into a JSON string.  Instead, try  serializing the Map object in your controller.  It sounds like your keys are integers, so:

```
Map<Integer, String> csm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
csm.put(1, "valueone");
csm.put(2, "valuetwo");
csm.put(3, "valuethree");
String json = new Gson().toJson(csm, Map.class);
request.setAttribute("cs", json);
```

Now you have much less coding to do in the jsp, and you take advantage of the OO nature of Javascript by handling an object, and you eliminate the need to loop over the keys.

```
var csm = ${cs};
var1_toCheck = '1'; // string values - no need for parseInt()
var2_toCheck = '2';

// check to see if key is a property of the csm object using typeof csm[var1_toCheck] != 'undefined'
// check equality of var1 and var2 values (not sure I understand your intent with this logic)
if (typeof csm[var1_toCheck] != 'undefined' && var1_toCheck == var2_toCheck)
    alert('Found a match');
else
    alert('No match');
```

So you test for the presence of a key using `typeof csm[varToCheck] != 'undefined'`.  If you need to access the value from your map, use `csm[keyVar]`.  This way you treat the structure similarly on the server side and the client side, improving maintainability.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I think I keep getting confused between server side and client side ... and what I should process where...

Many Thanks